Unexpected message sent to websocket server
My python program includes the below websocket class and function. The fetch_price_data() function is triggered every 60 seconds by client-side JavaScript (index.js).
class WebSocketClient:
    def __init__(self, url="ws://localhost:8081"):
        self.url = url
        self.ws = None
    
    def connect(self):
        """Establish connection to the WebSocket server and close immediately."""
        try:
            self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
            self.ws.connect(self.url)
            print(f"Connected to WebSocket server at {self.url}")
            self.ws.close()  # Close the connection right after establishing it
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to WebSocket server: {e}")
            self.ws = None

    def send_data_to_websocket(self, df):
        """Send data to the WebSocket server."""
        try:
            self.ws = websocket.WebSocket()
            self.ws.connect(self.url)
            print("Sending data to WebSocket...")
            json_data = df.to_json(orient="records")

            # Create a structured message with type and payload
            message = {
                'type': 'price_data',
                'payload': json.loads(json_data) # Convert JSON string to a Python object
            }

            # Send the structured message as a JSON string
            self.ws.send(json.dumps(message)) # Serialize the message back to JSON
            print("Data sent:", message)
            self.ws.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to send data: {e}")
            
@app.route('/fetch-price-data', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_price_data():
    print('Fetching price data.............................')
    df = get_price_data()
    ws_client = WebSocketClient()
    ws_client.send_data_to_websocket(df)
    return jsonify({"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}), 200
    

The issue I have is that the return statement in the fetch_price_data() (required by Flask) is causing a message to be sent to the websocket server, which I didn't expect. I know this because the server.js file is giving the below output:
Received a message without a type. Message will not be broadcasted.Parsed message: { status: 'Data sent to WebSocket server' }

Relevant code in the server.js file:.
const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;  // For serving the HTML page

// Serve static HTML file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// WebSocket server on port 8081
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8081 });

// Broadcast to all WebSocket clients
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            client.send(data);
        }
    });
};

// Listen for incoming WebSocket messages from Python
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection established');

    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        const jsonData = data.toString();  // Convert the buffer to string
        console.log('Received data from Python:', jsonData);

        try {
            const message = JSON.parse(jsonData);  // Parse incoming message

            // Log parsed message structure
            console.log('Parsed message:', message)
    
            // Check the message type before broadcasting
            if (message.type) {
                // Broadcast the structured message to all connected clients
                wss.broadcast(jsonData);  // Send as is if it's already structured
            } else {
                console.warn('Received a message without a type. Message will not be broadcasted.');
                console.log('Message with warning: ', message)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing incoming message:', error);
        }
    });

Hoping someone might be able to explain why the return statement in the  fetch_price_data() function is sending a message to the websocket server and how to prevent this. I thought it would just be sent back to the HTTP client.
I'm wondering if this is a valid use of Flask combined with the websocket client.


Hoping someone might be able to explain why the return statement in the fetch_price_data() function is sending a message to the websocket server and how to prevent this.

@app.route('/fetch-price-data', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_price_data():
    print('Fetching price data.............................')
    df = get_price_data()
    ws_client = WebSocketClient()
    ws_client.send_data_to_websocket(df)
    return jsonify({"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}), 200

Decomposing the fetch_price_data function:
df = get_price_data()

Here, you're initializing df with the result of fetch_price_data (a recursive call to itself). So, right now:
df = {"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}

Then, we create an instance of the WebSocketClient class and call its method send_data_to_websocket, passing df which we assigned the value of {"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}.
ws_client = WebSocketClient()
ws_client.send_data_to_websocket(df)

The send_data_to_websocket takes the value {"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}, checks for the key type, sees that it is undefined, and warns "Received a message without a type. Message will not be broadcasted.".
It looks like you're trying to use a Pandas dataframe somewhere, maybe you've defined the fetch_price_data function multiple times?
The way you're trying to use WebSockets is not right. You shouldn't close the connection immediately after opening it, this defeats the purpose of WebSockets. You don't need to poll the server from the client (JS) for updated information, this is the advantage of WebSockets: After the initial connection has been established, the server can send data to the client without the client initiating the connection.
I suggest reading up more on how WebSockets work and how to implement them in Flask. Personally, I like the Flask-Sock library.

Hello, the get_price_data() function does return a dataframe as df and the contents of it successfully get sent to the websocket server as expected. There is no issue with any lines in the fetch_price_data() function except the return statement line.
I do not understand why that is also sending data to the websocket server.
return jsonify({"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}), 200

Sorry, I totally misread the function. Can you provide a little more context about what you're trying to achieve? Why do you have two websocket servers communicating with each other? If you're calling the fetch_price_data function from your index.js, what is the point of the Node websocket server?

Sure. The client-side index.js calls fetch('http://localhost:5000/fetch-crypto-data) every 60 seconds which ends up executing fetch_crypto_data() function in the python program which gets price data, returns it as a dataframe, invokes the WebSocketClient() as ws_client, then uses the ws_client.send_data_to_websocket(df) to send the dataframe to the websocket server.
I just need the client-side javascript to trigger the code in the python script (every 60 secs) to get the price data as a df and send that to the websocket server to update the web page.

Just to add that the script is doing what I intend, but I still don't understand why return jsonify({"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"}), 200 is also resulting in {"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"} being sent to the web socket server. Could it be that using Flask and my WebSocketServer() instance are incompatible with one another?
I am importing and using the below in the python program:
import websocket from flask import Flask, jsonify, send_from_directory

I think I'd have to see your index.js file as well to understand why {"status": "Data sent to WebSocket server"} is being sent to the web socket server. I'm still unclear as to why you're using two websocket servers here. Why don't you just get the price data in the Node server?
